# Send Confirmation email to the USer Who Filled a Form

Tags: php, html, email

This is My HTML Form

```
 <form method="post" name="myemailform" action="form-to-email.php">
<p>
    <label for='name'>Enter Name: </label><br>
    <input type="text" name="name">
</p>
<p>
    <label for='email'>Enter Email Address:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="email">
</p>
<p>
    <label for='message'>Enter Message:</label> <br>
    <textarea name="message"></textarea>
</p>
<input type="submit" name='submit' value="submit">
 </form>
```

And this is PHP Mailing code which Grabs the data when user clicks submit

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{

echo "error; you need to submit the form!";
}
$name = $_POST['name'];
$visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

//Validate first
if(empty($name)||empty($visitor_email)) 
{
echo "Name and email are mandatory!";
exit;
}
$email_from = 'tom@amazing-designs.com';//<== update the email address
$email_subject = "New Form submission";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from the user $name.\n".
 "Here is the message:\n $message".

$to = "khan.koder@gmail.com";//<== update the email address
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";

mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

//done. redirect to thank-you page.

header('Location: thank-you.html');

?>
```

It shows no error but just land on the page thank-you.html I checked my email account but no mail recieved

Please help whats wrong

Comment: funny that's exactly what I thought when I saw your question!

Comment: There must be lot of tutorial for send mail through php ,of course after form submission (register form will have lot of examples.) . Just search with google should be enough.

Comment: Ok Got through an example but not working let me Edit my question @Dale

Comment: @Dale Now got it Solved it through Google Thanx Buddy

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it as follow:

1) create an activated field in database (default to **false**).
2) Upon registration, the email is sent
3) Populate a link in the email, to include...

```
a) user unique identifier 
b) activation to active
```

so it would look something like this potentially
[code]
Welcome **username_**. Thanks for registering, please click on the link below to activate your account
domain.com/register.php?uid=100&activate=1

4) Your registration script attempt to grab the user by the id.
5) Update the activated field to **true**.

And there u have a new and active user.

May it will give you an idea.